# AWS steps parallel state to orchestrate EMR jobs

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

We are orchestrating data pipeline with AWS steps and we do need to run EMR jobs in parallel.
I have tried using Map state and it works as expected. The only problem with Map is that in case one step fails , it cancels all the other steps as well. To overcome this issue , I am thinking if we can create an array of steps and pass it dynamically to **Branches** in **parallel state** but I have not been able to do it as it is not accepting strings.
Is there a workaround for this or can we only hard code branches in Parallel state? Can States.Array() in someway be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the inner state machine in a one-branch parallel state and add error/retry policies to it. Basically, you want to catch all errors and ensure that the iteration always succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for providing your inputs Pooya. 
The problem with parallel state is that I will need to hardcode everything which doesn't make life easier if you have to schedule 50 parallel jobs.We are currently reading metadata from s3 and then use map state to dynamically add steps to EMR. Furthermore, Error/Retry logic will work fine with the exceptions like API throttling but the moment there is a runtime exception(say dirty source data for one table), we are in the same situation where all other EMR steps are aborted as that particular table load will fail after the retries as well.

Comment: My suggestion was not about replacing map with parallel. My suggestion is to keep map and add a wrapper (parallel state) inside it.

Comment: I doubt if it resolves the issue of aborting the other Map iterations. I have task state with retry logic inside my map and a catch block for the Map itself. Wouldn't all other parallel states(inside Map) also be cancelled when one map iteration fails?

Comment: No map iteration will fail if you catch it inside.

Comment: I got what you were trying to say. I have kept a catch block inside the task state inside Map and transitioned it to a pass state within Map in case one iteration fails. What I could not do is to transition the Map state to another state in case there is a iteration failure. Is there a possibility of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who is trying to look for a solution to the stated problem. As suggested by Pooya, I did use catch block inside task within the Map rather than keeping it at map level.The state machine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BSRz.png)